# How to use data from google docs to show markers on google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a spreadsheet named contacts with columns - name, location, contactEmail.
How do I import this data to google maps in javascript?

Comment: I asked this a week or two ago and got nothing. The obvious answer is https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ with a lot of Ajax but there are also Fusion Tables. Let's hope someone has a better answer.

Comment: See the [Maps Service Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/maps_tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

If this is for personal use, I would recommend using Google Apps Script to load data from your spreadsheet and populate your map:
  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_maps

Additionally, you can even retrieve data from your Contacts list using the Contacts API.

Comment: Unfortunately the Maps Service generates static maps only. So what you get is a static image without the possibility to pan and zoom interactively or do any JavaScript magic with the map.